# Reading data using select in wix

Tags: wix, wix3.5, wix3.6

We are creating a installer package and we have
   requirement were we should be able to read values from table
   using select. I have searched a lot but didn't find anything to query the table.
   Is there any way to do it?
   Any examples?

Comment: Is it a database table? If so, what's the DB server? MS SQL? Oracle?